# M2Crypto Context using Engine in a HTTPS Connection

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using Python 38 and M2Crypto, Windows 7. I'm trying to establish an https connection with the certificate and private key of a USB token. And an error is generated when: m2.ssl_ctx_use_pkey_privkey (ctx.ctx, key.pkey):

This same routine works normally on a pfx file certificate.

code:

```
from M2Crypto import SSL, httpslib, X509, RSA, m2, Engine
slot_id = "slot_00"
pin = "1234"

engine = Engine.load_dynamic_engine("pkcs11", "c:/tests_python/pkcs11.dll")
pkcs11 = Engine.Engine("pkcs11")
pkcs11.ctrl_cmd_string("MODULE_PATH", "C:/WINDOWS/system32/OcsCryptoki.dll")
engine.init()     
r = pkcs11.ctrl_cmd_string("PIN", pin)
cert = engine.load_certificate(slot_id)
key = engine.load_private_key(slot_id)    

ctx = SSL.Context('tlsv1') 
m2.ssl_ctx_use_x509(ctx.ctx, certi.x509)
m2.ssl_ctx_use_pkey_privkey(ctx.ctx, key.pkey)        

ctx.set_verify(SSL.verify_none, depth=1)  
con = httpslib.HTTPSConnection('url', 443, ssl_context=ctx)
```

This error is generated on the line (m2.ssl_ctx_use_pkey_privkey (ctx.ctx, key.pkey):

Traceback (most recent call last): File "teste_m2crypto_ok.py", line 184, in xml_retorno = client.post_soap(xml_enviar, cabecalho, False) File "teste_m2crypto_ok.py", line 112, in post_soap m2.ssl_ctx_use_pkey_privkey(ctx.ctx, key.pkey) M2Crypto.SSL.SSLError: key values mismatch

Comment: you may try to check whether a certificate matched a private-key burned into your smart-card with `M2Crypto.m2.ssl_ctx_check_privkey(ctx.ctx)`. Add it right after loading key-pair into the `SSL.Context`.